Representability of cohomology theories in $\mathbb{A}^1$ homotopy category
I am new to algebraic geometry and $\mathbb{A}^1$ homotopy theory. My question is the following:

I know that the algebraic $K$ theory is reperesenatble in $\mathbb{A}^1$ homotopy category over smooth schemes. Now the. $K$ theory sheaf gives the chow groups for regular schemes. So does the Chow groups are representable in $\mathbb{A}^1$ homotopy category?

More generally,

Does there exists any condition on the cohomology theory for which it will be representable?

In particular,

Does the equivariant $K$ theory or the cellular $\mathbb{A}^1$ homology  is also representable?

Thanks in advance.
